# HTML CSS Boxes - Issue with Bootstrap Modal to trigger on clicking inside of box

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

my code is a mess and I know it.  I really just need some help.

I have a series of two codes for which people will want definitions.  When someone hovers over Code 1 and Code 2, it turns dark blue.  That part works fine. I want a Bootstrap Modal to pop up when someone clicks on the "block" or within the `<article>` and `</article>` tags. This would be easy with a button, but my users don't want a button.  I'm lost here and I've looked through various forums, codepens, etc and just haven't found the solution.  I know what I have here is messy, but I'm here to clean it up and get this resolved. Thank you in advance.

```
<main>
  <article><b>Code 1</b><br><br>
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-new">
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="body-message">
            <h4>Code 1 Title</h4>
              <p>Code 1 Definition
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</a>
  </article>

  <article><b>Code 2</b><br>

    <div class="wrap">

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-new">
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-new" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="body-message">
            <h4>Code 2 Title</h4>
              <p>Code 2 Definition
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</a>
  </article>
</main>

<style>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  /* Define Auto Row size */
  grid-auto-rows: 215px;
  /*Define our columns */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

article {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #55BBE9
  }

article:hover {
    background-color: #1B2631;
  }
  
modal-body {background-color: #55BBE9
}
</style>
```

Comment: You should be able to attach an click handler to the block. The click handler for that is then programmed to click the button for the modal open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `data-toggle="modal" data-trigger="click" data-target=".bs-example-modal-new"` to the `<article>` tags.

Example [here](https://codepen.io/nufrankz/pen/bGpWvjq)